# How do I solve it 'using $this'

Tags: php, this

```
function printPrice($price = null)
{
    $oCurrencyModel = getModel('currency');

    if(!$price && $this->price)
    {
        $price = $this->price;
    }
    return $oCurrencyModel->printPrice($price);
}

function printMileage($mileage)
{
    $oCurrencyModel = getModel('currency');

    return $oCurrencyModel->printPrice($mileage);
}
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/masanwatch/www/modules/nproduct/nproduct.item.php:89 Stack trace: #0 /home/masanwatch/www/files/cache/template_compiled/3a2e9f2cf85b939b1b1026ccb734f400.compiled.php(82): nproductItem::printPrice(0) #1 /home/masanwatch/www/classes/template/TemplateHandler.class.php(430): include('/home/masanwatc...') #2 /home/masanwatch/www/classes/template/TemplateHandler.class.php(197): TemplateHandler->_fetch('file:///home/ma...') #3 /home/masanwatch/www/classes/display/HTMLDisplayHandler.php(61): TemplateHandler->compile('./modules/ncart...', 'ordercomplete.h...') #4 /home/masanwatch/www/classes/display/DisplayHandler.class.php(64): HTMLDisplayHandler->toDoc(Object(ncartView)) #5 /home/masanwatch/www/classes/module/ModuleHandler.class.php(1153): DisplayHandler->printContent(Object(ncartView)) #6 /home/masanwatch/www/index.php(59): ModuleHandler->displayContent(Object(ncartView)) #7 {main} thrown in /home/masanwatch/www/modules/nproduct/nproduct.item.php on line 89

How do I solve it?

Comment: You're not using the function inside a class?

Answer (score 0):

if you use function in class you can call it by `$this` but if you use it in another page you must create object of that like this

```
class foo
{
     function printPrice($price = null)
    {
        $oCurrencyModel = getModel('currency');

        if(!$price && $this->price)
        {
            $price = $this->price;
        }
        return $oCurrencyModel->printPrice($price);
    }

    function printMileage($mileage)
    {
        $oCurrencyModel = getModel('currency');

        return $oCurrencyModel->printPrice($mileage);
    }
}

$bar = new foo;
$mileage = null;
$bar->printMileage($mileage);
```